# R or QGIS direction for distance

Tags: r, postgresql, qgis

Looking for either a R or QGIS solution: I have file with lat long, and group name.  I'd like to find either a) distance from a starting point to an end in a group, b) average distance between coordinates in a group, or c) something in between.  bonus if it has a cost function.  I've considered the r package gdistance but that seems like it's only distance between points.  I'd like to find a flow between the group. I also have postgresql access, but I don't have a lot of experience in that, so I'd prefer the other options. Ideas?

Comment: PostGIS and earthdistance?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the package `sp`. Specifically, the function `spDists`, which takes in a matrix of longitudes and latitudes, and returns a matrix of pairwise distances from each point to all other points.

With this utility, you could imagine creating a workflow where you feed in one group of locations at a time to a function which calculates distances between them. You could then take this matrix output, and calculate averages in whatever way you'd like.

The following reproducible example will help you get an idea how to get started.

```
require(ggmap)  # Used for 'geocode' function.
require(sp)     # Used for 'spDists' function.

### spDists spits out distance in KM if longlat argument = T.
  # Write a function to convert to miles.
kmToMile <- function(x) x * 0.621371

### Create a character vector of locations to be geocoded.
locs <- c("san francisco", "new york city", "los angeles", "miami, florida")
ll <- lapply(locs, geocode)
ll <- do.call(rbind, ll)

###          lon      lat
### 1 -122.41942 37.77493
### 2  -74.00594 40.71278
### 3 -118.24368 34.05223
### 4  -80.20404 25.78910

### Feeding in a matrix of points to spDists returns a matrix
  # of pairwise distance calculations. Use longlat argument to request
  # kilometers rather than the "metric of the points".
dist <- spDists(as.matrix(ll), longlat = T)

### Convert object from kilometers to miles.
  # Add row and column names, for easier reading.
dist <- kmToMile(dist)
rownames(dist) <- locs
colnames(dist) <- locs

###                san francisco new york city los angeles miami, florida
### san francisco         0.0000      2571.930    347.1645       2593.075
### new york city      2571.9305         0.000   2450.8558       1087.392
### los angeles         347.1645      2450.856      0.0000       2337.818
### miami, florida     2593.0752      1087.392   2337.8179          0.000
```

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to project your data if it is in geographic co-ordinates before calculating distance  . The pointdistances (Distances Among Points) tool in GME should do part of what you are asking, you may have do do  a few extra steps to get the data in the format you require  on the output from GME. There is more info here http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/pointdistances.htm

GME is a stand alone program which uses r to do the analysis, so you have to install this separately. Hope this helps.